# .NET MAUI: How to add an XAML page as the content of a Syncfusion sfTabItem

Tags: xaml, maui, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion's sfTabView for my MAUI app and I have the content of all my tabs set as Pages from seperate files to avoid my main page being 1000+ lines long.

The problem is that sfTabItems do not directly support Pages as content so I have them wrapped in a grid, which works in debug mode, but crashes on start if I run it not in debug mode. Is there a workaround for this?

```
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
xmlns:tabView="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.Maui.TabView;assembly=Syncfusion.Maui.TabView"

<tabView:SfTabView>
    <tabView:SfTabView.Items>
        <tabView:SfTabItem>
            <tabView:SfTabItem.Content> <!-- content does not directly support ContentPages -->
                <Grid>
                    <views:HomePage /> <!-- allowed (in debug) when wrapped in a grid -->
                </Grid>
            </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
        </tabView:SfTabItem>
    </tabView:SfTabView.Items>
</tabView:SfTabView>
```

The first error in my device log is as follows:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
12-20 11:32:44.439  pixel_5_-_api_29    Error   4343        * Assertion: should not be reached at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/mini/mini-exceptions.c:456
```

Followed by:

```
Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
12-20 11:32:44.439  pixel_5_-_api_29    Error   4343    libc    Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 4343 (.myproject), pid 4343 (.myproject)
```

Comment: a TabView can't contain ContentPages, only ContentViews.

Comment: @Jason of course the answer was that easy, I wasn't aware of ContentViews. Changed all my ContentPages to ContentViews and it works now. Thanks!